# Can the intersection of 2 non-regular languages be a regular language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages

Can the intersection of 2 non-regular languages be a regular language ?

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific. I can't see why it couldn't be. You could have a left-field OO language "crossed" with a functional language, and end up with something like Scala.

Comment: This is not what is meant by "regular" and "non-regular" languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that the two non-regular languages are distinct and have no strings in common.  The intersection of these 2 languages will be the empty set, since no string exists in both languages.

The empty set is a regular language, so this can happen sometimes.

Comment: Thank you very much , this was the most simple answer. What about the union ?

Comment: No problem. The example I remember for this is L1 = set of all palindromes over {a,b} and L2= L1 complement.  Both of these are non-regular, and the intersection is {}. Sometimes it's not obvious what will turn out to be a counterexample and what won't.

Comment: I believe it can be either regular or non-regular.  In the example I gave, L1 union L2 would be {a,b}*, a regular language.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose L and L' are non-regular languages. Can we conclude that L intersection L' is not regular?
The answer to this question can be found [here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/360Book/RegLang/Properties/Answers/6.html)